# Different result between stored procedure and query execution

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure with mysql with Navicat and when I execute this stored procedure I got 0 rows but when I execute the part of the stored procedure which I want I get 1 row which is what I want. The stored procedure is this:

```
BEGIN
#Routine body goes here...

IF @autor=0 THEN

 SELECT DISTINCT bdocus.ano_pub
  FROM            bdocus INNER JOIN
                     descriptores_bdocus ON bdocus.nserie = descriptores_bdocus.nserie INNER JOIN
                     descriptores ON descriptores_bdocus.iddescriptor = descriptores.id 
  WHERE        (bdocus.descriptores LIKE '%Victimización%')AND(bdocus.ano_pub LIKE CONCAT(@anyo,'%')) AND (bdocus.codigo_area LIKE CONCAT(@tema,'%')) AND(bdocus.codigo_colectivo LIKE CONCAT(@colectivo,'%')) AND (descriptores.nombre = @descriptores)
 GROUP BY bdocus.ano_pub
 ORDER BY bdocus.ano_pub DESC;
ELSE
 SELECT DISTINCT bdocus.ano_pub
 FROM            bdocus INNER JOIN
                     descriptores_bdocus ON bdocus.nserie = descriptores_bdocus.nserie INNER JOIN
                     descriptores ON descriptores_bdocus.iddescriptor = descriptores.id INNER JOIN
                     autores_bdocus ON bdocus.nserie = autores_bdocus.nserie
  WHERE        (bdocus.descriptores LIKE '%Victimización%') AND (autores_bdocus.idautor = @autor) AND(bdocus.ano_pub LIKE CONCAT(@anyo,'%')) AND (bdocus.codigo_area LIKE CONCAT(@tema,'%')) AND(bdocus.codigo_colectivo LIKE CONCAT(@colectivo,'%')) AND (descriptores.nombre = @descriptores)
  GROUP BY bdocus.ano_pub
  ORDER BY bdocus.ano_pub DESC;
  END IF;

END
```

Parameters are this:

```
IN `@anyo` varchar(20),IN `@tema` varchar(20),IN `@autor` int,  
IN `@colectivo` varchar(30),IN `@descriptores` varchar(40)
```

and the Values which I want are for `@anyo='2013'`,for `@tema='%'`,for `@autor=44439`,for `@colectivo='%'`and for `@descriptores='Violencia sexual'`.

When I run the second part of the stored procedure I mean:

```
SELECT DISTINCT bdocus.ano_pub
FROM            bdocus INNER JOIN
                     descriptores_bdocus ON bdocus.nserie = descriptores_bdocus.nserie INNER JOIN
                     descriptores ON descriptores_bdocus.iddescriptor = descriptores.id INNER JOIN
                     autores_bdocus ON bdocus.nserie = autores_bdocus.nserie
 WHERE        (bdocus.descriptores LIKE '%Victimización%') AND (autores_bdocus.idautor = 44439) AND(bdocus.ano_pub LIKE CONCAT('%','%')) AND (bdocus.codigo_area LIKE CONCAT('%','%')) AND(bdocus.codigo_colectivo LIKE CONCAT('%','%')) AND (descriptores.nombre = 'Violencia sexual')
GROUP BY bdocus.ano_pub
ORDER BY bdocus.ano_pub DESC;
```

I get as result a row with the value which I want. So where is the difference?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the value of autor?

Comment: Autor is 4439 as you can see on the select query.

Comment: Can you post `procedure` signature? i.e. parameter statement of the procedure as is that used while creating SP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to indicate the difference between [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) and routine parameters [13.1.15. CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html), are different variables.

In your example `@anyo` maybe is `NULL` and `` `@anyo` `` is assigned to `'2013'`.

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64214/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I think that you ain't getting the result because of the condition, i mean, your procedure ain't going to the 'else' part, therefore you are not getting that result. What you can do, is to try running the first select separatly

```
SELECT DISTINCT bdocus.ano_pub
  FROM            bdocus INNER JOIN
                     descriptores_bdocus ON bdocus.nserie = descriptores_bdocus.nserie INNER JOIN
                     descriptores ON descriptores_bdocus.iddescriptor = descriptores.id 
  WHERE        (bdocus.descriptores LIKE '%Victimización%')AND(bdocus.ano_pub LIKE CONCAT(@anyo,'%')) AND (bdocus.codigo_area LIKE CONCAT(@tema,'%')) AND(bdocus.codigo_colectivo LIKE CONCAT(@colectivo,'%')) AND (descriptores.nombre = @descriptores)
 GROUP BY bdocus.ano_pub
 ORDER BY bdocus.ano_pub DESC;
```

Just to see if is the same result as the whole procedure, and if you get 0 rows like when you run the procedure, it's probably that that's reason. Try to change the condition in order to get the first select being checked first(which is the one you need mostly i assume), and then going for the other.

Should be something like

```
-- see that i changed the condition
IF @autor != 0 THEN

 SELECT DISTINCT bdocus.ano_pub
 FROM            bdocus INNER JOIN
                     descriptores_bdocus ON bdocus.nserie = descriptores_bdocus.nserie INNER JOIN
                     descriptores ON descriptores_bdocus.iddescriptor = descriptores.id INNER JOIN
                     autores_bdocus ON bdocus.nserie = autores_bdocus.nserie
  WHERE        (bdocus.descriptores LIKE '%Victimización%') AND (autores_bdocus.idautor = @autor) AND(bdocus.ano_pub LIKE CONCAT(@anyo,'%')) AND (bdocus.codigo_area LIKE CONCAT(@tema,'%')) AND(bdocus.codigo_colectivo LIKE CONCAT(@colectivo,'%')) AND (descriptores.nombre = @descriptores)
  GROUP BY bdocus.ano_pub
  ORDER BY bdocus.ano_pub DESC;
  END IF;

ELSE

SELECT DISTINCT bdocus.ano_pub
  FROM            bdocus INNER JOIN
                     descriptores_bdocus ON bdocus.nserie = descriptores_bdocus.nserie INNER JOIN
                     descriptores ON descriptores_bdocus.iddescriptor = descriptores.id 
  WHERE        (bdocus.descriptores LIKE '%Victimización%')AND(bdocus.ano_pub LIKE CONCAT(@anyo,'%')) AND (bdocus.codigo_area LIKE CONCAT(@tema,'%')) AND(bdocus.codigo_colectivo LIKE CONCAT(@colectivo,'%')) AND (descriptores.nombre = @descriptores)
 GROUP BY bdocus.ano_pub
 ORDER BY bdocus.ano_pub DESC;

END
```

Try it and tell me how it goes, other thing that it can be, are the parameters you are putting when calling the procedure